# Microphone to Mixer Issues

Tags: microphone, sound, mixer

I have a [Weymic Professional Mixer | 7-Channel 2-Bus Mixer/w USB Audio Interface](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XCY3XZL).

I am using a [Pyle 3 Piece Professional Dynamic Microphone Kit Cardioid Unidirectional Vocal Handheld MIC with Hard Carry Case & Bag, Holder/Clip & 26ft XLR Audio Cable to 1/4'' Audio Connection (PDMICKT34)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HZAGWEA).

I am trying to connect the microphones to the mixer, but I am not getting any sound from the mixer. The cable is XLR to 1/4 inch jack. Where do I insert the 1/4 inch end on the mixer: insert or line? I tried both and I got no sound coming from the mixer. The microphone will not even turn on. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The microphones have 600ohms balanced outputs: it doesn't really make sense to connect them with the unbalanced cables delivered with them.  You *can* do so by plugging them into the "line" inputs of the mixer, but you'll need plenty of gain (and push volume) to get something out, and the level and impedance mismatch will not make the best use of your rather low-price equipment.

Instead you'll want to get proper XLR cables for connecting the microphones to the microphone inputs.  While the microphones should not mind phantom power, they don't need it, and the budget mixer probably produces less noise (and draws less USB power) when you switch phantom power off.